# sending a python request to a different host on the same network

Tags: python, rest, http, flask, python-requests

Currently I have something called a client, and a server.py that is running a flask server. I also have a different machine running a different flask server. (With the host being the ip address of the machine)

on one of the app routes, it will reroute the request to the different machine (Because of reasons) to process

Essentially, it looks something like this

server.py

```
@app.route('/endpointapi', methods = ['POST'])
def doStuff():
    f = request.form['message']
    correctURL = "http://somenumber.2.3:port/endpointapi"
    r = requests.post(correctURL, data={'message', f})
    return r
```

differentMachineOneSameNetwork.py

```
@app.route('/endpointapi', methods = ['POST'])
def doStuff():
    //does things correctly
    return updated message
```

The somenumber.2.3 is a valid ip address of the machine that is running differentMachineOneSameNetwork.py along with the port. Both machines are running a flask webserver, but the client can only send requests to the server.py. However, it is not connecting. Is there any reason why it might not be working?

*EDIT*

The ports are artifically chosen. 5555 for the server.py, and 8090 for the different machine. It works when we just test connections from the same machine to its own using curl commands, but it does not work when we try to curl from server machine to the other machine.

Whats working:

Curl from server to server flask

Curl from differentMachine to differentMachine flask

Curl from differentMachine to server flask

Not working:

Curl from server to differentMachine doesn't work. Connection just times out. Example command that was sent:

curl -X POST -F "message=some bojangle" http://correct.ip.address:8090/endpointapi

I get:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to correct.ip.address port 8090: Connection timed out

It just times out after trying to establish a connection, giving http response code of 500.

Comment: If you login to the host that's running the Flask server, and try to `curl http://somenumber.2.3:port/endpointapi`, does it work? If not, the problem has nothing to do with your code in `server.py`, so you're trying to debug the wrong thing. If so… well, then you're going to have to show us the actual exception if you expect us to debug it.

Comment: PS, starting off with "I will get directly to the point" is unnecessary, and avoids actually getting directly to the point.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

I can curl from the server machine to the server flask. I can not curl from server machine to the other flask server.

Comment: OK, if you can't curl from the server machine to the other flask, then that's the problem you have to debug. So (a) it may be a network problem rather than a code problem, in which case you're not even asking in the right place, and (b) if not, you need to edit your question to remove everything about the front-end server and instead show us how you configured the service server with an example of your `curl` command failing.

Comment: okay thanks for letting me know. I updated my question but I guess theres a possibility that it is the network itself that is the issue. Thanks

Comment: What IP address is differentMachine's flask bound to? It sound kinda like its `127.0.0.1` (internal loopback), not `0.0.0.0` (external nics).

Comment: Are they actually on the same network? If the backend server is behind a NAT and the frontend server is not, but has a public IP address, then you'd see exactly the symptoms you're seeing. (Of course there are other ways to get that, but this is the most obvious one.)

Comment: The machine ip addresses are bound to 192.168.x.xx.

They are on the same network. We can verify it through the network management system.